# list(file) appends \n to each line

Tags: python, list, file, python-2.7

Was reading the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code:
>
> If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use `list(f)` or `f.readlines()`.

So I tried it:

```
with open(file) as f:
    dictionary = sorted(list(f))
#debug
print dictionary
```

And the result was:

```
['anuria\n', 'anus\n', 'anuses\n', 'anvil\n', 'anvils\n', 'anxiety\n',
'anxious\n ', 'any\n', 'anybody\n', 'anyhow\n', 'anymore\n',
'anyone\n', 'anyplace\n', 'any thing\n', 'anytime\n', 'anyway\n',
'anywhere\n', 'anywise\n', 'aorta\n', 'aortae \n', 'aortal\n',
'aortas\n', 'aortic\n', 'aortitis\n', 'aoudad\n', 'aoudads\n',
'apace\n', 'apache\n', 'apaches\n', 'apanage\n', 'apart\n',
'apathies\n', 'apathy'...]
```

Two questions:

1. Why is the `\n` newline feed present?
2. Is there a way to remove it? Or I have to use `readline()` and append manually?

Comment: Note the last entry lacks the newline - clearly list() is giving you the contents of the file and the file contains newlines (if you open it in a notepad style application you will see newlines)

Comment: I copy pasted from console so I might have truncated the 'last entry' (there's like 50k words or more - didn't let it run till completion)

Comment: Fair enough, but the point still stands - the `list()` method is giving you the contents of the file - it isn't "adding" anything.

Comment: @MattCoubrough I get where you're coming from. Probably I should've said "Why didn't it strip the \n" instead of asking why is it there. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newline character is there because each line in the file ends with it.  Python does not remove this character when reading in the data.

To remove the newlines, you can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) and call [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) on each line:

```
with open(file) as f:
    dictionary = sorted(line.rstrip() for line in f)
```

Also, your variable is somewhat misnamed; `sorted` does not return a dictionary but a list:

```
>>> sorted(i for i in xrange(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: What is the convention called when you do this: 
`line.rstrip() for line in f`

Yea you're right on the misnomer it's actually a list but just for my note that I'm reading the words from a dictionary

Comment: `line.rstrip() for line in f` is a generator expression.  I included a link to the documentation.  Basically, it is the same as a list comprehension `[line.rstrip() for line in f]` except that it produces items lazily (one-by-one instead of all at once).  This saves on memory because it avoids creating an unnecessary list.

Comment: It's quite hard to grasp that concept but I'll try to read more on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

some of the thing you can do: you can use strip to remove newline character:

```
with open(file) as f:
    dictionary = sorted(map(str.strip,list(f)))
    #debug
print dictionary
```

you can use slicing as last character will always be newline:

```
dictionary = []
with open(file) as f:
    for x in f:
        dictionary.append(x[:-1])   # it will append everything except last character that is newline
    #debug
print sorted(dictionary)
```

let lambda to do it:

```
with open(file) as f:
    dictionary = sorted(map(lambda x:x[:-1],f))
    #debug
print dictionary
```